# Method executing differently when same arguments are passed

Tags: java

Same arguments passed on the same method for the same object.  It usually will display true, which is what I expect.   But... sometimes it displays false.  About 2-3 out of 100 times.  What is wrong with this method that would be causing this behavior?

year, month, and day are instance variables containing "2012", "4", "1" respectively.

```
public boolean isInDateRange(String startDate, String endDate)
{
    if(startDate == null || endDate == null){
        return false;
    }
    Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
    today.set(Integer.valueOf(year), Integer.valueOf(month), Integer.valueOf(day));

    Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
    //subtract 1 from the month parameter because java.util.Calendar's months
    //go from 0 to 11 instead of 1 to 12.
    start.set(Integer.valueOf(startDate.substring(0, 4)), Integer.valueOf(startDate.substring(5, 7)) - 1, Integer.valueOf(startDate.substring(8, 10)));

    Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();
    end.set(Integer.valueOf(endDate.substring(0, 4)), (Integer.valueOf(endDate.substring(5, 7))) -1 , Integer.valueOf(endDate.substring(8, 10)));

    return today.compareTo(start) >= 0 && today.compareTo(end) <= 0;
}
```

And here is what I am passing to it

```
calendarDetails.getTuesday().isInDateRange("2012-05-01 00:00:00", "2012-05-01 00:00:00")
```

Comment: Edited.  Knew I was forgetting something.  I pass it the same values in a loop 100 times.

Comment: Is this homework or so? If not, why not just using `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`? The `Date` has `before()` and `after()` methods. The `SimpleDateFormat` allows easy coversion between `String` and `Date`.

Comment: Not homework.  I suppose I wasn't using Date because most of those methods say deprecated and suggest using Calendar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're ignoring the time in your calculations. On the few occasions that the millisecond ticks over between `Calendar today = ...` and `Calendar start = ...`, you end up with `today`, `start`, and `end` having the same value for the date, but the time of both `start` and `end` is ahead of `today`. Specifically, they're 1 ms ahead since you're using `Calendar.getInstance()`, which returns the current time, to build all three of them. So when that tick happens, `today` isn't between `start` and `end`. You should zero out the time if you don't care about it.

Answer (score 0):

Post more information to help you better like for which inputs it is giving wrong result.

your program is working fine.

I think One Date can not be both greater than and less than other date.

You are passing same date in both the arguments. `(2012-05-01 00:00:00)`.

Moreover you can debug yourself ,print dates whenever you are not getting expected results.